# How to check if a given english sentence contains all non-meaning words using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, nltk

I want to check in a Python program if a given english sentence contains all non-meaning words.

Return true if sentence has all words that have no meaning

e.g. sdfsdf sdf ssdf fsdf dsd  sd

Return false if sentence contains at least one word that has meaning

e.g. Hello asdf

Here is the code I wrote.

**Updated the code for is_meaningless variable**

```
import nltk

nltk.download('words')

from nltk.corpus import words

def is_sentence_meaningless(sentence):
  is_meaningless = True
  for word in sentence.split():
    if(word in words.words()):
      is_meaningless = False
      break
  return is_meaningless    


print(is_sentence_meaningless("sss sss asdfasdf asdfasdfa asdfasfsd"))

print(is_sentence_meaningless(" sss sss asdfasdf asdfasdfa asdfasfsd TEST"))
```

Is there a better alternative to this code? Also, how can I add my own corpus to it? For example I have few domain specific words that I want it to return as true, is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `set.difference` method (note that since words in `nltk.corpus.words` are mostly in lower case, have to use `str.lower` method as well, e.g. "hello" is in but "Hello" isn't):

```
def is_sentence_meaningless(sentence, domain_specific_words):
    s_set = set(sentence.lower().split())
    if s_set.difference(words.words()+domain_specific_words) == s_set:
        return True
    return False
```

Just FYI but your function does not do what your explanation says.

Comment: Depending on the version of Python you can use the `-` operator e. g `set(sentence.split()) - words.words()`

Comment: @CutePoison you're right. `-` is also valid.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the word list contains only unique words, the function can be made more efficient by converting the list to a set.

Also, your logic doesn't seem to align with the implied purpose of the function (based on its name). A sentence would be meaningless if any of the words in the sentence are not found in the corpus set.

There is a considerable overhead in converting the word list to a set. Therefore, if the function is going to be used multiple times, it would be better to wrap it in a class.

Thus:

```
import nltk.corpus

class sentence_checker:
    def __init__(self):
        self.words = set(nltk.corpus.words.words())
    def is_sentence_meaningless(self, sentence):
        for word in sentence.split():
            if not word in self.words:
                return True
        return False

sc = sentence_checker()
print(sc.is_sentence_meaningless('hello'))
print(sc.is_sentence_meaningless('hellfffo'))
```

Comment: print(sc.is_sentence_meaningless('sssss asas')) should return False, but returns true

Comment: Remember, the function is called is_sentence_meaningless. That sentence is meaningless so it returns True

Comment: In all cases it returns True.

Comment: Try passing the sentence 'hello world' it will return False - i.e., it is not meaningless